# mysql query to select all except something

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to select the customers who purchase only vegetables in food table.But i can't use except in query.How can i do this?

```
    create table Order (
        email varchar(30),
        nOrder integer,
        primary key (email, nOrder),
        foreign key (email) references Client(email)
    );

    create table RegisterOrder (
        email varchar(30),
        nOrder integer,
        nameA varchar(30),
        primary key (email,nOrder,nameA),
        foreign key (email,nOrder) references Order(email, nOrder),
        foreign key (nameA) references Dishe(nameA)
    );

create table Dishe(
    nameA varchar(30),
    primary key (nameA),
    foreign key (nameA) references Food(nameA));

    create table Food ( 
      nameA varchar(30), 
      type varchar(30),
      primary key (nameA)
    );
```

Comment: Show what u tried and what u got?

Comment: What about using NOT IN()?

Comment: `order` is a reserved word in mysql, so those cannot be your table creation statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ro.email
from registerorder ro 
inner join food f on f.namea = ro.namea
group by ro.email
having sum(f.type <> 'vegtables') = 0
```

Comment: i got this while trying to compile:
RROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'f.nameA' in 'on clause'

Comment: @user2002274, the join should be on ro.nameF, not ro.nameA.. or you just left that out of your table structure as presented

Comment: my mistake on top, i edit the original post, name of food is always nameA

Comment: the tables dont have any error, but the querie provided by you doesnt..
i updade my tables and now they are right.. sorry for mistakes..

Comment: This works! thank you and sry for my errors.
the problem was that i have my code in portuguese and translate it to you and left nameA instead of nomeA.. but is ok now, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example...

```
 SELECT * FROM recipes;
 +-----------+---------------------------------+
 | recipe_id | recipe                          |
 +-----------+---------------------------------+
 |         6 | Beans & Macaroni                |
 |         9 | Beans on Jacket Potato          |
 |         3 | Beans on Toast                  |
 |        10 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast                 |
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese               |
 |        12 | Peanut Butter on Toast          |
 |         5 | Toast & Jam                     |
 +-----------+---------------------------------+

 SELECT * FROM recipe_ingredient;
 +-----------+---------------+
 | recipe_id | ingredient_id |
 +-----------+---------------+
 |         1 |             1 |
 |         1 |             2 |
 |         2 |             2 |
 |         2 |             4 |
 |         3 |             3 |
 |         3 |             4 |
 |         4 |             2 |
 |         4 |             3 |
 |         4 |             4 |
 |         5 |             4 |
 |         5 |             5 |
 |         6 |             1 |
 |         6 |             3 |
 |         9 |             3 |
 |         9 |             6 |
 |        10 |             2 |
 |        10 |             3 |
 |        10 |             6 |
 |        12 |             4 |
 |        12 |             7 |
 +-----------+---------------+

 SELECT * FROM ingredients;
 +---------------+---------------+
 | ingredient_id | ingredient    |
 +---------------+---------------+
 |             3 | Beans         |
 |             2 | Cheese        |
 |             6 | Jacket Potato |
 |             5 | Jam           |
 |             1 | Macaroni      |
 |             7 | Peanut Butter |
 |             4 | Toast         |
 +---------------+---------------+
```

The following returns a list of all recipes and the ingredients required to construct them...

```
 SELECT r.*
      , i.*
   FROM recipes r
   JOIN recipe_ingredient ri
     ON ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
   JOIN ingredients i
     ON i.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id;
 +-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
 | recipe_id | recipe                          | ingredient_id | ingredient    |
 +-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
 |         6 | Beans & Macaroni                |             1 | Macaroni      |
 |         6 | Beans & Macaroni                |             3 | Beans         |
 |         9 | Beans on Jacket Potato          |             3 | Beans         |
 |         9 | Beans on Jacket Potato          |             6 | Jacket Potato |
 |         3 | Beans on Toast                  |             3 | Beans         |
 |         3 | Beans on Toast                  |             4 | Toast         |
 |        10 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |             2 | Cheese        |
 |        10 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |             3 | Beans         |
 |        10 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |             6 | Jacket Potato |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |             2 | Cheese        |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |             3 | Beans         |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |             4 | Toast         |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast                 |             2 | Cheese        |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast                 |             4 | Toast         |
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese               |             1 | Macaroni      |
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese               |             2 | Cheese        |
 |        12 | Peanut Butter on Toast          |             4 | Toast         |
 |        12 | Peanut Butter on Toast          |             7 | Peanut Butter |
 |         5 | Toast & Jam                     |             4 | Toast         |
 |         5 | Toast & Jam                     |             5 | Jam           |
 +-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Now let's suppose we have a pantry containing Cheese, Beans, and Toast. What can we construct using ONLY those ingredients?

```
 SELECT r.*
      , SUM(CASE WHEN ingredient IN ('Cheese','Beans','Toast') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) x
      , COUNT(*) y
   FROM recipes r
   JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
   JOIN ingredients i ON i.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id
  GROUP
     BY r.recipe_id;
 +-----------+---------------------------------+------+---+
 | recipe_id | recipe                          | x    | y |
 +-----------+---------------------------------+------+---+
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese               |    1 | 2 |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast                 |    2 | 2 | <-- 
 |         3 | Beans on Toast                  |    2 | 2 | <--
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |    3 | 3 | <-- *
 |         5 | Toast & Jam                     |    1 | 2 |
 |         6 | Beans & Macaroni                |    1 | 2 |
 |         9 | Beans on Jacket Potato          |    1 | 2 |
 |        10 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |    2 | 3 |
 |        12 | Peanut Butter on Toast          |    1 | 2 |
 +-----------+---------------------------------+------+---+

 x = y : recipes use only those ingredients found in the pantry.

 x = y = total no of ingredients in pantry : recipes using EXACTLY the ingredients found in the pantry
```

This can be rewritten thus...

```
 SELECT r.*
   FROM recipes r
   JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
   JOIN ingredients i ON i.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id
  GROUP
     BY r.recipe_id
 HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN ingredient IN ('Cheese','Beans','Toast') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*);
```