# make request using many differents table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a request depending on many tables and I am a bit lost. I'll try to explain the best I can with what I have tested..

So, I have a physical activity application. I have a list of exercices and all exercices use different materials.

For this I have a table `EXERCICES` with (name, id_exo) then I have a table `EXERCICES_MATERIEL` with (id_exo and id_materiel) and and table `LISTE_MATERIEL` with (id_materiel and name_materiel).

```
In EXERCICES_MATERIEL I have 
id_materiel: 1, name_materiel: bench 
id_materiel: 2, name_materiel: barbell
id_materiel: 3, name_materiel: plates
id_materiel: 4; name_materiel: chin-up bar
```

Then, I have some sessions which are made with many blocs. A session is a 10mn workout which can be composed of many lines :
for example : 10 reps of bench press then 10 reps of chin-up then 1mn rest

So in table `SESSIONS` I have one line : id : 1 and name : upper-body

And in table `BLOC` I have 3 lines :

```
id_session : 1, exo: 2 (for bench press), rep: 10, time: 0
id_session : 1, exo: 1 (for chin-up), rep: 10, time: 0
id_session : 1, exo: 3 (for rest), rep: 0, time: 1
```

Now I want to make a request which gives me the `SESSIONS` depending of the materiel that I have. And more, it needs to give me the `SESSIONS` if I can do it, meaning I have all the materiel.

Materiel for bench-press : bench, barbell, plate
Materiel for chin-up: chin-up bar

So basically, if I tell I have only chin-up bar, it should not give me id_session 1 but if I have all the materiel it should give it to me.

Here is what I have started to do :

```
SELECT id_session, count(id_session) as second_count 
FROM BLOC 
WHERE id_exo IN (SELECT id_exo 
                FROM EXERCICES_MATERIEL 
                WHERE id_materiel = (3))
                GROUP BY id_session
```

So with this request I get all lines in `BLOC` where the exercice match with the materiel 3 (so plates).

But in this case, I will then get id_session 1 or I should not since I have only plates and not the other materiel needed for this session (i.e. bench + barbell)

Also, with this request, I got the rows of `BLOC` and me I'd like to get the id_session of `SESSIONS` corresponding to those rows in `BLOC`.

Hope I have explained it correctly and someone could help me with this.

Here is the query to make a duplicate of the example.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SESSIONS (
    id_session INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name_session VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BLOC (
    id_session INT,
    id_exo INT,
    rep INT,
    time INT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LISTE_MATERIEL (
    id_materiel INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name_materiel VARCHAR(100)

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXERCICES (
    id_exo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name_exercice VARCHAR(100)

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXERCICES_MATERIEL (
    id_exo INT,
    id_materiel INT
);

INSERT INTO `SESSIONS` (`id_session`, `name_session`) VALUES (NULL, 'bench + chin-up');
INSERT INTO `SESSIONS` (`id_session`, `name_session`) VALUES (NULL, 'only bench press');
INSERT INTO `SESSIONS` (`id_session`, `name_session`) VALUES (NULL, 'only chin-up');

INSERT INTO `LISTE_MATERIEL` (`id_materiel`, `name_materiel`) VALUES (NULL, 'bench');
INSERT INTO `LISTE_MATERIEL` (`id_materiel`, `name_materiel`) VALUES (NULL, 'barbell');
INSERT INTO `LISTE_MATERIEL` (`id_materiel`, `name_materiel`) VALUES (NULL, 'plates');
INSERT INTO `LISTE_MATERIEL` (`id_materiel`, `name_materiel`) VALUES (NULL, 'chin-up bar');

INSERT INTO `EXERCICES` (`id_exo`, `name_exercice`) VALUES (NULL, 'chin-up');
INSERT INTO `EXERCICES` (`id_exo`, `name_exercice`) VALUES (NULL, 'bench press');
INSERT INTO `EXERCICES` (`id_exo`, `name_exercice`) VALUES (NULL, 'recup');

INSERT INTO `EXERCICES_MATERIEL` (`id_exo`, `id_materiel`) VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `EXERCICES_MATERIEL` (`id_exo`, `id_materiel`) VALUES ('2', '2');
INSERT INTO `EXERCICES_MATERIEL` (`id_exo`, `id_materiel`) VALUES ('2', '3');
INSERT INTO `EXERCICES_MATERIEL` (`id_exo`, `id_materiel`) VALUES ('1', '4');

INSERT INTO `BLOC` (`id_session`, `id_exo`, `rep`, `time`) VALUES ('1', '2', '10', '0');
INSERT INTO `BLOC` (`id_session`, `id_exo`, `rep`, `time`) VALUES ('1', '1', '10', '0');
INSERT INTO `BLOC` (`id_session`, `id_exo`, `rep`, `time`) VALUES ('1', '3', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `BLOC` (`id_session`, `id_exo`, `rep`, `time`) VALUES ('2', '2', '30', '0');
INSERT INTO `BLOC` (`id_session`, `id_exo`, `rep`, `time`) VALUES ('3', '1', '15', '0');
```

RESULT EXPECTED

With my user interface, I will select the material I have (so basically I have choice between bench, barbell, plate, and chin-up bar).

Then, I need to display the SESSION that I can do with the materiel I will select. So if I select all 4, I should get as a result id_session 1, 2 and 3 from SESSION but if I select only 2 or 3 materiels, it should give me no session since it's not possible to make the session if I do not have all the materiel.
For example, if I select only chin-up bar I should get only id_session = 3 since for id_session 1 I need chin-up bar but also another materiel.

For now I am able to do this query :

```
SELECT b.* FROM BLOC b
WHERE id_exo IN (
SELECT e.id_exo
   FROM exercices e
   JOIN EXERCICES_MATERIEL em ON em.id_exo = e.id_exo
   JOIN LISTE_MATERIEL lm ON lm.id_materiel = em.id_materiel
  GROUP BY e.id_exo
 HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN name_materiel IN ('bench','barbell','plates') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*))
```

If returns me all the rows where I can do the exercices. But it's not enough. I got id_session 1 and 2, but I should not get id_session = 1, since there is a row where I have chin-up exercice and I do not have the materiel for it.
So basically, it should return all row only if all id_session are true...

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post with all the query to make a replicate of the db. @Strawberry

Comment: I'm still not clear what the input is, and what the output should look like for the given input.

Comment: Updated again at the end to try to explain what I'd like to get. Thank you for you help. @Strawberry

Comment: At present, your data set (with only one session) is too minimal to be representative. We need to see the 'edge cases' too.

Comment: But essentially, this is a pantry query: "Given the following ingredients, what recipes can I make?"

Comment: E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930070/mysql-query-to-select-all-except-something/19931269#19931269

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this. I have upadted the post to add 3 sessions to have more possibility and also update the RESULT EXPECTED. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226863/discussion-between-tom-and-strawberry).